# How to get node name/display value using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

This is my xml

```
 <Governing_Law_TermName displayValue="NZ Law">
   <Governing_LawText>This is the text within</Governing_LawText>
</Governing_Law_TermName>
```

I want to extract the term 'NZ Law' but it's not the value within a node, but defined as its displayValue.

I tried the following but did not work:

```
name(//Governing_Law_TermName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XPath expression, the sub-expression `//Governing_Law_TermName` identifies the element, and the `name()` function will return the name of that element i.e. `Governing_Law_TermName`, which is obviously not what you want.

What you actually want is to traverse from the `Governing_Law_TermName` element to its `displayValue` attribute. Follow the path along the `attribute` axis like so:

```xml
//Governing_Law_TermName/attribute::displayValue
```

... or in its more commonly used shorthand form:

```
//Governing_Law_TermName/@displayValue
```

Note that in the terminology used for XPath, the `Governing_Law_TermName` is a "node", and so is the `displayValue` attribute, as is the `Governing_LawText` element and also the text `This is the text within`. Text nodes, elements, and attributes (among others) are all different kinds of node.